# Conditional Unique ID for each record excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have two values in different columns. Column A have Department name i.e. HR, Admin and Ops. and column be have date. I want Unique ID in column C based on Combination of Column A & B and Unique number at the end.

```
Unique ID: HR-Aug-16-1
           Admin-Aug-16-1
```

this number will be repeat till the combination of Column A and B repeated 50 times after 50 times last value will be increased by +1. i.e.

```
HR-Aug-16-2
Admin-Aug-16-2
```

Right now I am using formula,

```
=A1&"-"&TEXT(B1,"mmm-yy")&"-1"
```

Answer (score 0):

In C1 as a standard formula,

```
=A1&"-"&TEXT(B1,"mmm-yy")&CHAR(45)&INT((SUMPRODUCT(--(A$1:A1&TEXT(B$1:B1, "mmm-yy")=A1&TEXT(B1, "mmm-yy")))-1)/5)+1
```

I've set this to repeat after 5 for an example. I'll leave it to you to change the modifier to 50. Fill down as necessary.

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot lot Jeeped. I am actually looking the same. Kindly explain if possible.